# How to run the second service only if the first service Done using Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have two services the first service will POST ID of the file and then I will get responses these responses contain some information that I need to pass it to second service, so the second service will act as the input of the first service and take the response as parameter to GET data. the issue is the second service didn't wait the response from the first and I got id=Undefined

Services:

```
DownloadFileById(body) {
  const observable = from(
    this.apiService.getInstance().webScript.executeWebScript('POST', 'URL', body)).pipe(
        map((data) => {
           console.log("data from Service", data.entry);
           return data;
          }
        ));
   return observable;
}

GetFileDetail(nodeId:string) {
   const observable = from(
        this.apiService.getInstance().webScript.executeWebScript('GET',`URL/${nodeId}`)).pipe(
              map((data) => console.log("GetFileDetail service", data))
             );
       return observable;
 }
```

Component.ts

```
public DownloadMyFile(file) {
      const body = {
            nodeIds:file
      };
      this.service.DownloadFileById(body).subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.entryNode = data.entry;
        },
        () => {
             console.log('Error');
        }
     );
     this.service.GetFileDetail(this.entryNode.id).subscribe(
          () => {console.log("GetFileDetail", this.entryNode)},
          () => {console.log('Did not receive id')}
         );
  }
```

I think should to use the RXJS operators, but I really don't know how to do it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are handling asynchronous code in a synchronous way. That's why the second service is not waiting for the first one to finish.

This can be easily fixed with some of the `rxjs` mapping operators

```typescript
export function DownloadMyFile(file) {
  const body = { nodeIds: file };

  this.service.DownloadFileById(body)
  .pipe(
    // Use tap operator to assign data.entry to this.entryNode
    tap(data => this.entryNode = data.entry),
    // Check how the data object looks
    tap(data => console.log('DATA:', data)),
    // Use concatMap to call GetFileDetail only after DownloadFileById succeeded 
    concatMap(data => this.service.GetFileDetail(data.entry.id))
  )
  .subscribe(
    (data) => {
      // data - in subscribe are now result from GetFileDetail()
      console.log("GetFileDetail", this.entryNode);
      console.log('Did not receive id');
    },
    () => {
      console.log('Error');
    }
  );
}
```

EDIT: Added `tap` with `console.log`

Comment: Really thank you for your response , NOW the second service doesn't run until the first service finish but still I get undefined.  this Request URL: GET http://localhost:4200/public/versions/1/downloads/undefined/

Comment: Did you try to call it this way: `this.service.GetFileDetail(data.entry.id))`. Since I don't know how your model looks it might be the issue. I edited my answer with one short `tap` before the `GetFileCall`, to see what data you have.

Comment: I just updated the code now and wrote this command this.service.GetFileDetail(data.entry.id)), it actually worked. 
The problem was that I needed to write  .entry before id. Really, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The switchMap operator is used to switch to the GetFileDetail request once the response from DownloadFileById is received. This ensures that the GetFileDetail request is made with the correct entryNode.id value.

Now, the second service will wait for the response from the first service before executing, and you should no longer encounter the issue of id=undefined.

```
this.service.DownloadFileById(body).pipe(
    switchMap(data => {
      this.entryNode = data.entry;
      return this.service.GetFileDetail(this.entryNode.id);
    })
  ).subscribe(
    () => {
      console.log("GetFileDetail", this.entryNode);
    },
    () => {
      console.log('Error');
    }
  );
```